# How to select images inside a div with JS / jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an array called "works" that contains 7 images.
They should be displayed in a grid which is defined like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="g-work">
  </div><!-- / row -->
</div><!-- / container -->
```

Now in JS I am filling/replacing "works" with these images and then I want to turn the borders red. However I don't really understand how to select them correctly. This is supposed to be the correct code but it doesnt seem to work. What is this `$("#g-work img)` doing? There are no image tags in `#g-work`. What does it mean? And why can't just write `var images=works`? If I try the code below, my developer tools even tell me that images is not defined. What is the problem here?

```
for(var i = 0; i < works.length; ++i ) {
  $("#g-work").append("\
    <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-3'>\
      <img class='img-responsive' src='" + works[i] + "'>\
    </div>\
  ");

  var images = $("#g-work img"); 
  $(images[i]).css("border", "2px red");
};
```

Comment: Add your `works` array to your example

Comment: `$("#g-work img)` selects all images that are descendants of the element with the ID of `g-work`. The code you have before that would appear to append the images from the `works` array to that div, each wrapped in another div.

Comment: This the content of work.js:

var works = [
"img/pf1.jpg",
"img/pf5.png",
"img/pf6.jpg",
"img/pf7.png",
"img/pf2.jpg", 
"img/pf3.jpg", 
"img/pf4.jpg"];

I can follow you but when I type "works" into the console, if returns this area, while images seems undefined, but why?

Answer (score 1):

```js
works=["http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/s-That-look.jpg","http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/s-Yoshi-The-Seal-Kitteh.jpg"]
 
 $.each(works,function(key,value)
 {
   let DIV=$("<div/>",{class:"col-sm-6 col-md-3"});
   let Image=$("<img/>",{class:"img-responsive",src:value,style:"border:solid 2px red;margin-bottom:5px"});
   $(DIV.append(Image)).appendTo("#g-work");
 });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="g-work">
  </div><!-- / row -->
</div><!-- / container -->
```

Comment: A tip: instead of `$("#g-work").append(DIV.append(Image));` you could have used the properties (like you already do) i.e: `appendTo: "#g-work"` etc. Or even better, populate an Array with your DIV objects and than append to DOM only once after the loop (performance-wise) Something like: https://jsfiddle.net/rxz4yohf/

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan -Thank you so much. Really your description was helpful

Comment: Ok, this may work but the point of the exercise is to use basic loops and conditionals, I will add some moe code in order to make it clearer what the result should be.

Comment: You can check the terms in your loop and add the image to your father in different modes

Comment: For example, you can specify the color of the "border" based on the condition, and then add the style to the image

Answer (score 0):

Ok fond the source of the problem, I believe but I don't understand why its a problem. If choose "2px solid salmon" as border color, it works but if I take "2px red" or "2px ffffff", it doesn't.

```js
var works=["http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/s-That-look.jpg","http://www.cutestpaw.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/s-Yoshi-The-Seal-Kitteh.jpg"]



for(var i = 0; i < works.length; ++i ) {
  $("#g-work").append("\
    <div class='col-sm-6 col-md-3'>\
      <img class='img-responsive' src='" + works[i] + "'>\
    </div>\
  ");
  var images = $("#g-work img");
  
  
$(images[i]).css("border", "2px solid salmon");
//$(images[i]).css("border", "2px red");

};
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<div class="container">
  <div class="row" id="g-work">
  </div><!-- / row -->
</div><!-- / container -->
```

Comment: You must specify a style type in the image

Comment: What do you mean? Is "solid salmon" a part of a defined style or something, but "red" not?